# Memory leak because of Spring singleton

Tags: java, spring, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Because of lack of understanding, I used a spring bean in SINGLETON scope (default). I use this bean to just populate my data structures. The data-structure is populated in the init-method . After the population of my data structures, I don't need the bean any more.While I was profiling my application for possible memory leaks, I figured that this singleton object was occupying a lot of memory (it load a lot of data from the database).

I guess, the application context hold references of all the singleton beans till it shuts down. Now that I have become wise,I would like to fix the issue. By changing the definition of bean to PROTOTYPE, I think I would make the bean eligible for garbage collection as soon as it gets out of scope which is after it has run the init-method. My question is

1) Is this the correct way of dealing with the issue.
2) Shown below in the xml snip. DataPopulator is the bean which I would like to be garbage collected once it has executed its init-method. But it hold reference to a singleton object. How this does not hamper the garbage collection? Ideally it should not is what I think. Seeking your opinion.

```
<bean class="com.foo.DataPopulator" init-method="loadDataOnStartUp" **scope="prototype"**>
    <property name="moService" ref="moServiceRef" />
</bean>

<osgi:reference id="moServiceRef" interface="com.foo.IMoDAO"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a singleton bean for data initialization is not uncommon and I would prefer the singleton bean over a prototype. The memory usage is likely due to some member variables or static references within the bean that hold the large amount of data. Try refactoring this to only using local variables that can be garbage collected when the initialization has completed.

Comment: That's a good point. I agree that if I can work with local variables, I would not have to work about huge memory leaks as the stack would unwind itself. But still there would be a leak, but not as significant. Why not prototype scope which guarantees a garbage collection?

Comment: You hit it right. I re factored the code to include local variable and avoided memory leaks. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

It is better not to create a bean for `DataPopulator` at all if you just need to execute some method to init data in `moServiceRef` during app context startup. Use `@PostConstruct` in your `moServiceRef` to execute necessary method. If this is not an option you could try to use `ApplicationListener` and listen for the `ContextRefreshedEvent` to run your code.